# What is a good beginner resource to read about the information bottleneck theory?

Tags: reference-request, information-theory, online-resources

I am looking for preferably a tutorial/exercises/video lecture or otherwise a book that can help me understand the information bottle neck theory and apply it to a signal processing application.

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion, a PhD thesis wrote by one of Prof. Tishby's student is a very good start. http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/labs/learning/Theses/Slonim_PhD.pdf